# r dynamic variable naming from dataframe columns

Tags: r, dynamic, session-variables

Dynamic variable naming from dataframe columns

I have a two question test from a pool of several hundred questions. There are two question columns, and two response columns. I need to create new columns named by the question values and assign responses from the corresponding response values

A table of the data is as follows

```
question1     question2    response1     response2

SI089923       SI089801        B             A

WK090824       WK090712        C             B

WK091040       WK090843        D             C

question1 <- c('SI089923','WK090824','WK091040')
question2 <- c('SI089801','WK090712','WK090843')
response1 <- c('B','C','D')
response2 <- c('A','B','C')

arrayQuestion <-paste( "question", 1:2, sep="")
arrayResponse  <-paste( "response",  1:2, sep="")
```

I tried code found on this site but got an object not found error

```
for (i in 1:2){
  varname <- eval(parse(text=paste(arrayQuestion[i], sep="")))
  varvalue <- eval(parse(text=paste(arrayResponse[i], sep="")))
  eval(parse(text=paste(varname, varvalue, sep=" <- ")), envir=.GlobalEnv)
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is your desired output? In your sample data it looks like the column names already have the values you are trying to assign to them.

Comment: Maybe you're just trying to code your own version of `attach()`? The general recommendation is *don't ever use `attach`*, but using `attach` is preferable to rolling your own, worse version of `attach`. Try `attach(your_data)` and see if it does what you want.

Comment: The final output includes variable names: question1 question2 response1 response2 SI089923 SI089801 WK090824 WK090712 WK091040 WK090843

Comment: @Gregor  Actually, there now ten variables and ten columns with the responses assigned according to which items were assigned to each of the three examinees in the example dataset.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to clarify question regarding the form of the final data frame the column names are abbreviated to a character width of five:

```
ques1 <- c('SI083','WK094','WK090')
ques2 <- c('SI081','WK092','WK093')
resp1 <- c('B','C','D')
resp2 <- c('A','B','C')
```

> Initial data frame:

```
>ques1 ques2 resp1 resp2
>SI083 SI081   'B'   'A'
>WK094 WK092   'C'   'B'
>WK090 WK093   'D'   'C'
```

> The final data frame:

```
>ques1 ques2 resp1 resp2 SI083 SI081 WK094 WK092 WK090 WK093
>SI083 SI081   'B'   'A'   'B'   'A'
>WK094 WK092   'C'   'B'               'C'   'B'
>WK090 WK093   'D'   'C'                           'D'   'C'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution, although I do not know if it is the most efficient approach available in R.  This program will read a data frame containing columns of variable names and columns of variable values and dynamicaly create new columns based on the variable names and assign the applicable varible values to the new columns.

```
names1  <- c('SI923','WK824','WK040') # vector of variable names
names2  <- c('SI801','WK712','WK843') # "
values1 <- c('B','C','D')             # vector of variable values
values2 <- c('A','B','C')             # "

require(reshape2)
dfOne <- data.frame(names1,names2,values1,values2)
print(dfOne)
```

> Here is the printed output of the data frame

```
  names1 names2 values1 values2 
1  SI923  SI801       B       A 
2  WK824  WK712       C       B 
3  WK040  WK843       D       C
```

> Here is the code to encode the new variables

```
namesCol  <-paste( "names",  1:2, sep="") # vector of data frame column names
valuesCol <-paste( "values", 1:2, sep="") # vector of data frame column names

for (j in 1:nrow(dfOne)){
  for (i in 1:length(namesCol)){
    namesCol.i<-eval(namesCol[i])       # data frame column name of variable names
    varname<-eval(parse(text=paste(namesCol.i,'[j]',sep='')))
    if (exists(varname)==FALSE){
      eval(parse(text=paste('dfOne$',varname,'<- NA',sep='')))
    }
    valuesCol.i<-eval(valuesCol[i])     # data frame column name of variable values
    varvalue<-eval(parse(text=paste(valuesCol.i,'[j]',sep='')))
    if (is.character(varvalue)){
      eval(parse(text=paste('dfOne$',varname,'[j]','<-',"'",varvalue,"'",sep='')))
    }else{
      eval(parse(text=paste('dfOne$',varname,'[j]','<-',varvalue,sep='')))
    }
  }
}  
print(dfOne)
```

> Here is the printed output of the data frame with the newly encoded variables

```
  names1 names2 values1 values2 SI923 SI801 WK824 WK712 WK040 WK843
1  SI923  SI801       B       A     B     A  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
2  WK824  WK712       C       B  <NA>  <NA>     C     B  <NA>  <NA>
3  WK040  WK843       D       C  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>  <NA>     D     C
```